# mediacontroller not anchored to video frame layout

Tags: java, video, android-framelayout, mediacontroller

I'm trying to view videos in my app, but the problem is that the media controller doesn't stay docked to the video. In fact, if I scroll down the page, the media controller of the first video is located on the buttons

[image]

the code of the adapter is this:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VideoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String videoURL = videoURLs.get(position);

        VideoView videoView = holder.videoView;
        FrameLayout customMediaController = holder.customMediaController;

        // crea un mediaController personalizzato
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(holder.itemView.getContext());
        // collega la VideoView al MediaController
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        // imposta il MediaController per la VideoView
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

        // gestione manuale della posizione del MediaController
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        customMediaController.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        .......
    }
```

the code of the xml file is this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <!-- Pulsante Play -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/playButton"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/larghezza_bottone_piccolo"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/altezza_bottone_piccolo"
        android:text="@string/avvia"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/video_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/playButton">

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/custom_media_controller"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp">
        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/delete_icon"
        android:contentDescription="@string/elimina"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playButton"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/downloadButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_download_24"
        android:contentDescription="@string/download"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/deleteButton"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I can't solve this problem, i've tried so many things